# Computing eigendecomposition of a Hermitian matrix that is almost unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, eigensystem, eigenvalues, dense-matrix

I have a dense Hermitian matrix that is approximately unitary, so it has eigenvalues that are $\sim \pm1$. I would like to compute all the eigenvectors corresponding to the $+1$ eigenvalue (not necessarily a small fraction of the total number of eigenvalues). Is there some more efficient way to accomplish this than tridiagonal QR?

Comment: Look for the kernel of $A-I$?

Comment: Now that I re-read your question, it is not clear to me whether you mean "the eigenvalues that are exactly +1", or "those that are closer to +1 than to -1 and hopefully come from +1 eigenvalues of the unperturbed unitary matrix". Could you clarify?

Comment: I mean the latter. The eigenvalues "should" be clustered around $\pm1$, but practically, get spread out a bit, while still respecting the upper bound (but not the lower). Typically, of the set closer to $+1$, the vast majority of them are almost exactly $1$.

Answer (score 1):

A thing you might try:

1) perform a few iterations of the matrix sign iteration $A\mapsto \frac{1}{2}(A+A^{-1})$; the eigenvectors are unchanged, while the eigenvalues converge quadratically to $\pm 1$. When $A-A^{-1}$ is small enough, stop the iteration.

2) compute the kernel of $A-I$.

More information on the matrix sign iteration on the book N. Higham, *Functions of Matrices*.

This method trades off eigensolves for QR factorizations; it might be faster than QR, depending on the size of the matrices, of the perturbation, and other machine-related factors difficult to quantify.